# Is there a reason to enclose a Windows batch file set command in quotes?

Tags: cmd

I've programmed Windows batch files for almost as long as Windows has been around and I've typically used:

`set counter=0`

However, I've been reviewing a legacy batch file and it has:

`set "counter=0"`

I know this is legal syntax according to `ss64.cmd` but are there any other benefits? The only one mentioned on `ss64.cmd` is that you don't get caught out by invisible trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicate

```
           v There is a space here
set  data=0 
set "data=0"         Avoid spaces at the end of the variable
```

But also

```
set data=^<^<^>^>
set "data=<<>>"      Include special characters without having to escape them
```

which can solve things as

```
C:\Tests\Cloak & Dagger files>set folder=%cd%
"Dagger"  is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file

C:\Tests\Cloak & Dagger files>set "folder=%cd%"

C:\Tests\Cloak & Dagger files>set folder
folder=C:\Tests\Cloak & Dagger files
```